# Querying an XML in SQL SERVER skipping boolean

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Simple put, I'm just trying to query a XML column (below) where:

1. I'm skipping the rows with one asterisk next to them
2. Only interested in the rows with two asterisks next to them

   -falsefalse*
   true*
   false*
   true**
   false**
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false
   false

Comment: But what is the actual logic? Or does your XML file actually have asterisks in it?

Comment: Sorry mate, the asterisks are there just to point out the rows I'm after

Answer (score 0):

try this,if not working then explain your criteria

```
Declare @i xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>-<ArrayOfBoolean xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean>
<boolean>true</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>true</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean>
<boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean>
<boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean><boolean>false</boolean></ArrayOfBoolean>'

;with cte as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by  (SELECT 0))rn from
(SELECT  col1 = col1.value('.', 'bit') 

FROM   
         @i.nodes('/ArrayOfBoolean/boolean') AS tag ( col1 ))tbl
)

select * from cte where rn>(select max(rn)+1 from cte where col1=1)
```